# Why is git submodule path wrong?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repository (which I'll refer to as `ml`) located at

```
ssh://ml-fey/usr/projects/data/nuclear/mc/type1
```

This repository has a submodule. The `.gitmodules` file looks like this

```
[submodule "Appendix"]
    path = Appendix
    url = /usr/projects/data/nuclear/mc/type1/Appendix
```

I can clone the repository to a new repository (which I'll refer to as `XL`), however when I try to update the submodule I get this error

```
$ git submodule update
Cloning into 'Appendix'...
fatal: '/usr/projects/data/nuclear/mc/Appendix' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Clone of 'ssh://ml-fey/usr/projects/data/nuclear/mc/Appendix' into submodule path 'Appendix' failed
```

Notice that the directory from which it is search for the `Appendix` submodule is missing the final `type1` directory. The reason git can't update the submodule in `XL` is because `ssh://ml-fey/usr/projects/data/nuclear/mc/Appendix` doesn't exist. Where did the `type1` go?

The `.gitmodules` file for the `XL` repository looks like:

```
[submodule "Appendix"]
    path = Appendix
    url = /usr/projects/data/nuclear/mc/type1/Appendix
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Submodules are also called out in your `.git/config` file. Is the URL correct in there? If not, you can use `git submodule sync` to sync things up.

Comment: this is exactly i was looking for. the redundancy in .gitmodules was confusing. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation yet, so I put it as new answer. Execute command `git submodule sync` inside the submodule directory, not parent git root directory.